# Simple Help with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need some help with a redirect:

How do I take any URLs with www.example.com/blog/ and anything else after it, (.*) and strip it down to just the text after /blog/?

I've never really done rewrites, so please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ index.php?$1
```